# Keep getting number of elements in the array as one javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the number of people logged in and i have a loop going through the list with a condition but it displays the number of elements in the array as one

I have tried using the forEach Loop and the for loop counter

```
employees.forEach(employee => {
        if(employee.clockIn == true){
          const arr=[]
          arr.push(employee.firstName)
          console.log(arr.length);
        }
      })
```

The expected result is two but i keep getting 1 and a small circle that has 2 inside in my console but it outputs as 1 in the DOM

Comment: You need to create `arr` outside of the `for` loop. Currently you are creating a new, empty array in each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) creates a block scope variable, so every time `(employee.clockIn == true)` evaluates to `true`, `arr` is recreated as an empty array. You should either create `arr` in the outer scope, or use more a functional approach, for example leveraging [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const clockedInEmployees = employees.filter(emp => emp.clockIn);
console.log(clockedInEmployees.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you are creating a new array every iteration of your loop.

An easier way to do this might be by using `filter`

```
var clockInEmployees = employees.filter(employee => employee.clockIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re creating the array on each iteration, you might want to hoist the declaration of the array outside the loop:

```
const arr = [];
employees.forEach(employee => {
    if(employee.clockIn == true){      
        arr.push(employee.firstName)
        console.log(arr.length);
    }
});
```